# $\sum{\frac{1}{n^n}}$ is convergent on divergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$\sum{\frac{1}{n^n}}$ is convergent on divergent ?

$n^n > n!$

$\frac{1}{n^n}<\frac{1}{n!}$

$\sum{\frac{1}{n!}}$ is convergent by ratio test.

Therefore $\sum{\frac{1}{n^n}}$ is convergent by comparison test.

But, using divergence test for $\sum{\frac{1}{n^n}}$

$a_n=\frac{1}{n^n}$

$lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=1$

therefore it must diverge.

I know I did something wrong here but unable to figure out. Please help

EDIT: Thanks guys

I applied $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^n = 1 $ which is wrong. I was actually thinking $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n} = 1 $

$\sum{\frac{1}{n^n}}$ is very much convergent

Comment: "$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=1$": NO. Perhaps you were thinking about $\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^x=1$.

Comment: Ahhh actually was thinking $ \lim_{n\to\infty} n^{1/n}=1$

Comment: You won't run into many series more convergent than $\sum 1/n^n.$ Think how small those terms are!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is convergent by comparison test. Note that $1/n^{n} \leq 1/n$ for all $n$; so $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n^{n}} = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Use that $\sum \frac12^n < \infty$. Then it follows by the direct comparison test.

Carl